# Download csv file from a query resultset as larg as a 50000 rows in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, csv

I have a function in my controller that downloads csv file for a Linq query resultset. The linq query simply fetches data from the database for a user provided date range.

```
var dataForDateRange = obj.table.Where(m => m.id== id && m.CreatedDateTime >= start && m.CreatedDateTime<= end);
string csv = string.Empty;
foreach(var csvData in dataForDateRange)
{
    csv = csvData.col1 + "," + csvData.col2 + "," + csvData.col3......;
    csv += "\r\n";
}
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="+engineName+"_CSV.csv");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/text";
Response.Output.Write(csv);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

The above code works successfully for a smaller number of datarows. The browser timesout if the records go beyond 10000. Debugging shows that the code hangs at the foreach loop. 
What is the best way to get this done for about 500000 records?

Comment: For starters, you probably want to switch to using a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.7.1) when building your `csv` file. The way your code is now you are potentially creating thousands of temporary strings.

Comment: I would convert this to use a datatable from there I would use a lambda statement to quickly export this to a csv using the datatable.. this is much quicker..

Comment: @pstrjds *`He has terabytes of memory clearly, efficiency is for chumps.`*

Comment: For situations like this, I would recommend a different approach. Let the user fire the request, process it in the background, monitor completion, save the file in your server and provide a link when the file is ready so the user can download.

Comment: @Greg - it's not just the memory pressure, there is a performance issue that goes with that. Although, from a rough calculation, if there are only 4 columns with 10 characters of data each, at 500000 rows we are looking at a roughly 40 MB file. So not sure this is a good approach even with a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @pstrjds I used the sarcastic font, I agree with you.

Comment: @Greg - Sorry, past my bedtime and misread it.

Comment: look into using / creating `SSRS reports`

Comment: use https://filehelpers.net (or any other CSV library) to create the CSV document

Comment: I'm amazed that this code is described as working successfully with a small amount of data. I'd suspect some *"The result shows only one line"* problem.

Comment: Thanks all, using string builder worked for now.. Will try implement different things from your comments for better optimization

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder Class & FileStream to generate csv.
Try below code. 
You can include **System.Text** for StringBuilder & **System.IO** namespace to use FileStream class.

```
var dataForDateRange = obj.table.Where(m => m.id== id && m.CreatedDateTime >= start && m.CreatedDateTime<= end);
StringBuilder csvBuilder = new StringBuilder();

//Adding column header
csvBuilder.AppendLine("Col1","Col2", "Col3", ....);

//Adding row data
for(int i = 0; i < dataForDateRange.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    csvBuilder.Append(dataForDateRange.Rows[i] + ",");
    csvBuilder.Append("\n");
}

//Save your file
public void SaveFileReport()
{
    try
    {
        if(File.Exists("yourfilepath") == false) //eg @"c:\test.csv"
        {
            FileStream fstream = File.Create("yourfilepath"); 
            fstream.Close();
        }
        File.WriteAllText("yourfilepath", csvBuilder.ToString());
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

//Note: I have given the basic logic to implement, request you to add your code 
 and debug to get desired result.

Comment: It would probably be better to use somewhat valid syntax even if you don't write all the details. Like `csvBuilder.AppendLine("Col1,Col2,Col3, ...");` for the headers instead of a non-existing `AppendLine` that looks as if it accepts many parameters. Also you could keep the question notation of `foreach(var csvData in dataForDateRange)` and `csvData.col1, csvData.col2 ...` for the column access. Potentially use `Append("{0},{1},...", csvData.col1, ...).AppendLine()` or something similar to mimic the question behavior in a valid and stringbuilder-compliant way.